# Any way to follow further requests in one web page?

Tags: scrapy, python-requests

I need to download a web page with intensive ajax. Currently, I am using Scrapy with Ajaxenabled. After I write out this response, and open it in browser. There are still some requests initiated. I am not sure if I was right that the rendered response only includes the first level requests. So, how could we let scrapy include all sub-requests into one response?

Now in this case, there are 72 requests sent as opening online, where 23 requests as opening offline.

Really appreciate it!

Here are the screenshots for the requests sent before and after download

[requests sent before download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05QYt.jpg)

[requests sent after download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rZDC.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
class SeedinvestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "seedinvest"
    allowed_domains = ["seedinvest.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.seedinvest.com/caplinked/bridge',
    )

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        item = SeedinvestDownloadItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['html'] = response.body
        yield item
```

Comment: add the link and your code

Answer (score 0):

The code is as follows:

```
class SeedinvestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "seedinvest"
    allowed_domains = ["seedinvest.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.seedinvest.com/startmart/pre.seed',
    )

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        item = SeedinvestDownloadItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['html'] = response.body
        yield item
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include this code. Your code does not belong as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reminding, I have edited the questions again.